# Django TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable

Tags: django, view

I have some trouble with one of my functions in my projects view file.
I have tested with removing this function and then things work.

This is my view file:

```py
def createPurchaseOrder(request):           
    form = PurchaseOrderForm()
         if request.method == 'POST':
              form = PurchaseOrderForm(request.POST)
               if form.is_valid():
               form.save()
               return redirect('/')
    context = {'form':form}
    return render(request, 'order_form.html', context)
```

Here is the HTML file with the link which tries to access the view

```html
{% for order in orders %}
    <tr>
        <td>{{order.po_number}}</td>
        <td>{{order.product}}</td>
        <td>{{order.status}}</td>
        <td><a href="{% url 'update_order' update_order.id %}">Update</a></td>
        <td><a href="">Delete</a></td>
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

I also have attached the `urls.py`:

```py
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', views.home, name="home"),
    path('supplier/<str:pk>/', views.supplier, name="supplier"),
    path('products/', views.products, name="products"),
    path('purchase_order/', views.purchase_order, name="purchase_order"),
    path('order_form/', views.createPurchaseOrder, name="create_purchase_order"),
    path('update_order/<str:pk>/', views.updatePurchaseOrder, name="update_order"),
]
```

I expect there to be a simple mistake, but can't seem to find it.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\jenny\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\socketserver.py", line 650, in process_request_thread
    self.finish_request(request, client_address)
  File "C:\Users\jenny\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\socketserver.py", line 360, in finish_request
    self.RequestHandlerClass(request, client_address, self)
  File "C:\Users\jenny\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\socketserver.py", line 720, in __init__
    self.handle()
  File "C:\Users\jenny\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\servers\basehttp.py", line 172, in handle
    self.handle_one_request()
  File "C:\Users\jenny\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\servers\basehttp.py", line 197, in handle_one_request
    handler.run(self.server.get_app())
  File "C:\Users\jenny\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 145, in run
    self.handle_error()
  File "C:\Users\jenny\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\servers\basehttp.py", line 119, in handle_error
    super().handle_error()
  File "C:\Users\jenny\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 382, in handle_error
    self.finish_response()
  File "C:\Users\jenny\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 184, in finish_response
    self.write(data)
  File "C:\Users\jenny\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 288, in write
    self.send_headers()
  File "C:\Users\jenny\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 345, in send_headers
    if not self.origin_server or self.client_is_modern():
  File "C:\Users\jenny\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 358, in client_is_modern
    return self.environ['SERVER_PROTOCOL'].upper() != 'HTTP/0.9'
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```

Comment: Please share the *full* traceback.

Comment: I also get this, which is related. Reverse for 'update_order' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['update_order/(?P<pk>[^/]+)/$']

Comment: Probably it should be `<a href="{% url 'update_order' order.id %}">`?

Comment: Thank you, that worked, :) but where did you find that order.id from. another function? I thought i specified a variable in UpdatePurchaseOrder function and used that. The "update order" variable.

Comment: it is the iterator of your `{% for order in orders %}`.